# Python output method

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [2,3,1,0,2],
     [2,31,2,5,2],
     [12,3,2,2,3]]
flattenA = list(chain(*A))

def partition(lst, n):
    division = len(lst) / float(n)
    return [lst[int(round(division * i)): int(round(division * (i + 1)))] for i in xrange(n)]

for x in xrange(0,10):    
   random.shuffle(flattenA)

   for i in xrange(3,18):
       print"CLUSTER {}: ".format(partition(flattenA,i))
         Cal = [sum(e) for e in partition(flattenA, i)]
   result.append(Cal)
   min_total = min(result)
   print min_total
#now print 
just number ex) 12

#i want print 
min 6  list [1,2,3]
```

When I run it with my current coding, only the constant is output. What I've done so far is to split the list, compute the values inside, and print the smallest value. But what I want to ask is that when the smallest value is printed with applicable list. What should I do? if you let me know, i'm so appreciate

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to output the min and the list at the same time.

try

```
print 'min{0} list{1}'.format(min_total,result)
```